# What does it mean by "Objects are basic run-time entities in an object-oriented system"?

Tags: c++, oop

I recently started learning C++ and came across this sentence in a text book.Can anyone please explain what does this mean with an example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would guess what it's trying to say is that objects are the fundamental building blocks of an application within the object-oriented paradigm. "Run-time" refers to the fact that objects don't exist in source code; they are completely a run-time construct. The source code simply defines the *blueprint* for objects. We call such blueprints "classes."

Comment: A shame the book had to use the word _"object"_ again to describe what an object was.

Comment: @Micky, the book i am referring is a standard text book used here, in the engineering colleges , however if you know some better books for beginners, please do suggest. Thanks

Comment: @DigitalGeeK Can't think of any off-hand but this quick google search resulted in this nice  _"Objects are at heart very simple. They are a way to represent information about a "real world" idea and they contain ways to manipulate that information"_ - [Object Oriented Programming - University of Utah](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/oop.html).  It's perhaps offtopic but it doesn't repeat the term in the explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run time entities = thingies that exist only during program execution somewhere in memory. They have no life outside program execution.

For example, in C , the run-time entities are structures, basic types, etc .

In an Object oriented language, instead of basic types , the used entities are Objects (Of course previous types are also available, but those aren't what makes the Language Object Oriented).

In other words, in an OOP Language , you need to think about building solutions using (mostly) Objects .

Comment: Now i get it. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: But surely one of the features of C++ is that objects don't exist at runtime. They exist in the source code, but once the source code has been compiled there are just functions, structures and basic types. There is no reflection in C++.

Answer (score 1):

as the objects didn't get the memory space while they are formed i.e. in the source code.These objects gets the memory space at run time i.e. after the formation of .exe(executable file).

Answer (score 0):

**Objects** are kind of tools through which you can **access the variables inside a class**.These objects are **provided memory when instantiated**, that means memory is provided dynamically & hence called ***Run Time Entities***.

Answer (score -1):

Easy way to understand this concept is - Objects don't occupy memory at the time writing the source code. Instead of it they take memory at the time while we run the source code.